# How can I get class types declared inside an Angular 8 component seen inside AngularJS code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular8

I have an AngularJS application integrated with Asp.Net MVC backend project that i want to enhance it by using an in-house developed Angular 8 component so i did the followings:

1. I made an angular 8 library to host my component.
2. Inside the library module constructor i registered my component as web component/custom element by using angular/elements.
3. Back to AngularJS i created an Angular 8 project side by side to host the library and re-exported my library module again from the Angular 8 app module.
4. Then I put all of the Angular 8 distribution files [main-es2015,vendor-es2015,runtime-es2015 ..etc] inside the Layout.cshtml file.
5. Now when i use the new html element i.e the Angular 8 component inside AngularJS hosted html everything is fine and the component starts to work successfully.
6. But since the component needs a lot of configuration to work properly i created an input attribute inside it that intercept these configuration as an object instance from a class declared inside the component's library itself and of course it is exported via the "public-api.ts" file.
7. The problem is that class is undefined to AngulaJS code at all. I thought that importing one of the angular 8 distribution file to a "ts" file will make me see the type so i can instantiate an instance from it then pass it by any means to AngularJS controllers will work, but unfortunately i failed.

The question is how can I get the class type declared inside Angular 8 component seen inside the AngularJS code?

Comment: You need to import it in the AngularJS code.  regardless, there's no need to design your API so that it accepts only an instance of a class. Just take a plane object , that would be more idiomatic

Comment: @AluanHaddad
"You need to import it in the AngularJS code" ,yeah sure , but that was my question: how can i import it?
I tried to import the distribution files of the Angular8 app and i got "undefined"

Comment: Add your imports and exports to the question